# Data structure for text corpus database

Tags: python, database, database-design, sqlite, nlp

A text corpus is usually represented in xml as such:

```
<corpus name="foobar" date="08.09.13" authors="mememe">
  <document filename="br-392">
    <paragraph pnumber="1">
      <sentence snumber="1">
        <word wnumber="1" partofspeech="VB" sensetag="012345678-v" nameentity="None">Hello</word>
        <word wnumber="2" partofspeech="NN" sensetag="876543210-n" nameentity="World">Foo bar</word>
      </sentence>
    </paragraph>
  </document>
</corpus>
```

When I try to put a corpus into a database I had each row to represent a word and the columns are as such:

> | uid | corpusname | docfilename | pnumber | snumber | wnumber | token
>   | pos | sensetag | ne
>
> | 198317 | foobar | br-392 | 1 | 1 | 1 | Hello | VB | 012345678-v |
>   None |
>
> | 192184 | foobar | br-392 | 1 | 1 | 1 | foobar | NN | 87654321-n | 
>   World |

I put the data into an `sqlite3` database as such:

```
# I read the xml file and now it's in memory as such.
w1 = (198317,'foobar','br-392',1,1,1,'hello','VB','12345678-n','Hello')
w2 = (192184,'foobar','br-392',1,1,1,'foobar','NN','87654321-n','World')

con = sqlite3.connect('semcor.db', isolation_level=None)
cur = con.cursor()
engtable = "CREATE TABLE eng(uid INT, corpusname TEXT, docname TEXT,"+\
                        "pnum INT, snum INT, tnum INT,"+\
                        "word TEXT, pos TEXT, sensetag TEXT, ne TEXT)"
cur.execute(engtable)
cur.executemany("INSERT INTO eng VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", \
                                wordtokens)
```

The purpose of the database is so that I can run queries as such

```
SELECT * from ENG if paragraph=1;
SELECT * from ENG if sentence=1;
SELECT * from ENG if sentence=1 and pos="NN" or sensetag="87654321-n"
SELECT * from ENG if pos="NN" and sensetag="87654321-n"
SELECT * from ENG if docfilename="br-392"
SELECT * from ENG if corpusname="foobar"
```

It seems like when I structure the database as above, my size of database explodes because the number of tokens in each corpus can go up to millions or billions.

Other than structuring a corpus by having each row for a word and the columns its attribute and parental attribute, **how else could i structure the database such I can perform the queries and get the same output?**

For the purpose of indexing large size corpus,

1. should I be using some other database programs other than sqlite3?
2. And should i still use the same schema for the table as I have defined above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> And should i still use the same schema for the table as I have defined
>   above?

In perspective of relational database design, due to [1NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form), I will use a table per element of the xml file. 
We will save space and we will help DBMS performance. 
Using the model, desired queries will be appliable
The draft model will be:

[image: model]

> should I be using some other database programs other than sqlite3?

That may be answered based on your application specification, like how many data records you will have after a month, year, ... , how many users will be connected, is it a OLTP or OLAP or mixed, the projects budget and ... 
BTW take a look at free R-DBMS's like PostgreSQL,MySQL and commercial ones like Oracle. 
For NoSql solutions having a look on the [post](http://kkovacs.eu/cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-couchdb-vs-redis) may be helpfull

Answer (score 3):

I guess the obvious answer is "normalisation"... you have an enormous amount of duplicated information per row and that is going to massively increase the size of your database.

You should work out from each row what is duplicated and then create a table to contain that data and then you will reduce, for example, a duplicated string containing the corpus length of, say, 20 characters in length to a pointer to a row in the "corpus name" table which for arguments sake might just take 4 characters as the ID value of that entry.

You don't say what platform you are using either. If it is a mobile device then it really does pay to normalise your data as much as possible. It makes the code a little more complex but that is always the space/time trade-off with stuff like this. I am guessing that this is some kind of reference application in which case pure blinding speed is probably secondary to just making it work.

The mandatory wikipedia link for [normalisation](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FDatabase_normalization&ei=kzMsUpC5HoeFhQeV14GADw&usg=AFQjCNHZafTSNtxYQoeV7w3ZUnWInaSFoA&sig2=leDJc9xvivlj1fhpZt78dQ&bvm=bv.51773540,d.ZG4)

and this [YouTube video](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&ved=0CEIQtwIwAw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3Dfg7r3DgS3rA&ei=kzMsUpC5HoeFhQeV14GADw&usg=AFQjCNGDdhw6A4-OJUSwVlURAtTl2w8dPA&sig2=lP_AJICFcZBaFdB8AsMJrg&bvm=bv.51773540,d.ZG4)

Google is your friend, hope that helps. :) Sean

Comment: http://highscalability.com/blog/2008/7/16/the-mother-of-all-database-normalization-debates-on-coding-h.html

Comment: Just read that page and fell about laughing! Some salient points though and I would def. agree with de-normalisation being a last resort for efficiency reasons. In this case thought I think it would actually help.